# Postgis : ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm using POSTGIS="2.0.1 r9979" and facing following error :

```
ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "POINT(18.570275,7" <-- parse error at position 17 within geometry
CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_dwithin" during inlining
```

while trying sql :

```
 SELECT addressid FROM maddress 
  WHERE ST_DWithin(geocode, 'POINT(20.0924758 72.7341809 19.137381,72.837223)' , 100.0);
```

i wish to select the addresses between the points mentioned in query.

I have checked syntax and as per syntax i have put values in query.Please let me know the correction.

Comment: You will need to describe how you are creating your geometries, because that's what the error is.

Comment: @MikeT. OP answered in the comments, geocode turns out to be lat/lon fields separately, and if you look at the POINT it has a comma in. So, there are actually about 3 questions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to find points that are between two points, you probably need to use ST_DWithin twice, so that you get the points that are in the intersection of a circle based on  point 1 and a circle based on point 2, eg,

```
SELECT addressid FROM maddress 
WHERE ST_DWithin(geocode, ST_MakePoint(20.0924758, 72.7341809), 100.0)
AND ST_DWithin(geocode, ST_MakePoint(19.137381, 72.837223), 100.0);
```

Note that the units are in SRID units, which in your case appears to be 4326, so you might want to convert your coordinates to meters, use a geography data type, so the distance will be in meters, or convert the distance to degrees -- there are various choices. I'm sure you have seen the [ST_DWithin docs](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) that explains these options. You might also want to consider the **use_spheroid** parameter.

Instead of `ST_MakePoint` above, you can also use `ST_GeomFromText` which takes the form 'POINT(x y)' as you are originally had an optionally allows you to specify the SRID, eg, using 4326, you can also write the query as:

```
SELECT addressid FROM maddress 
WHERE ST_DWithin(geocode, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(20.0924758 72.7341809)',4326), 100.0)
AND ST_DWithin(geocode, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(19.137381 72.837223)', 4326), 100.0);
```

**EDIT** Following comments from OP, it turns out that geocode is not a geometry column. You can fix this by running.

```
ALTER TABLE maddress ADD COLUMN geom GEOMETRY  (POINT, 4326);
UPDATE maddress set geom=ST_MakePoint(lng,lat);
CREATE INDEX ix_spatial_geom on maddress using gist(geom);
```

You will then need to use geom instead of geocode in the queries above. I am assuming that your points are in 4326.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I left a comma in the 2nd one. A point has to be separated by spaces. I have edited the anser.

Comment: Sorry, had some coffee now. Right, you either need to use ST_GeomFromText('POINT(x y)') or ST_MakePoint(x,y). Have updated the answer.

Comment: Still showing same error "parse error at position 8 within geometry"

Comment: it is showing invalid geometry.why so? is the problem with geometry is invalid? anything else?

Comment: Which one are you trying, the first or the second. They both work for me. Make sure if you are using ST_GeomFromText you have two apostrophes and if ST_MakePoint you have no apostrophes.

Comment: i have tried second one.Is their any changes in table? I'm using my previous postgresql table.I didn't created a spatial table.why does it shows parse error?Is any parser configuration required?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. geocode is a geometry column, no? Either should work, as they are just different ways of creating points.

Comment: geocode stores (lat,long) points like (8.9750,72.8258).Actually i'm new for postgis.previously i have used postgresql

Comment: Ah, that wasn't very clear in your question. This will work a lot better if you create a geometry column and add a spatial index to it, as then ST_DWithin will use the index.

Comment: You need to create a geometry column too. I have updated the answer with this.

Answer (score 8):

I hade the same error when using:

```
select ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-27.75 ,114.75)', 3857)
```

instead of:

```
select ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-27.75 114.75)', 3857)
```

You need to remove the comma separator.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Migrations and change the type of field if you use Leaflet:

- django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields.MultiPointField

To

- from djgeojson.fields import MultiPointField